# Incompatible API error when using org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect with hibernate3-maven-plugin

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, hbm2ddl, hibernate3-maven-plugin

I had previously set my project up to use hibernate3-maven-plugin with org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect as the hibernate.dialect and everything was working fine.

But when I changed the dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2005Dialect, hibernate3-maven-plugin encounters the following error:

> An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2:hbm2ddl: java.land.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2005Dialect.registerColumnType(IJLjava/lang/String;)V

Does hbm2ddl support SQLServer2005Dialect or SQLServer2008Dialect (I also get the same error with 2008)?

I am using version 2.2 of the plugin and hibernate.4.1.0.Final and JPA 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Just lost a few days to the same error with gradle and glassfish.  I added my own SqlServer2005Dialect from source, and commented out the registerColumnType() lines.  From here, the error changed to "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE"

This is a much more [google-able](http://robert-reiz.com/2011/05/07/caused-by-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-instance/) error, and basically means you have 2 sets of hibernate jars.

In my case, I had installed hibernate via glassfish before hibernate was put into the gradle build.  Uninstalling hibernate from glassfish fixed my error, and I can now run the 2008 or 2005 dialects.

Comment: This sounds like a promising lead. I will have to investigate in the future. During the meantime, I simply used the newer SQLServer2008Dialect in the web app and the older SQLServerDialect for the plugin.